# ASP.net 3.5 converting existing website to responsive design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

i have got an existing website developed using asp.net 3.5. business requirement is such that it needs be accessed through mobile devices mainly and mostly tablets.
is there any way i can achieve that without converting the entire website to mvc4 or re writing the front end code?

Comment: i suggests u that convert width pixels into percentage in whole website wherever u give width in all pages.  @Ozil

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the viewport meta tag to at least scale the site on mobile devices, like so:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

But really, its impossible to make a site fully responsive and mobile friendly without changing the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's grid system is a quick and fairly easy way to get started with a responsive design. It is a 12-column fluid grid layout that stacks or expands as the screen size or device width changes, and comes with 4 preset widths to help you distinguish among mobile devices, tablets and desktops. You will have to restructure the front end to fit into the grid template, but this shouldn't require a total re-write.

Check out the docs and examples here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid